# Simple question about a sentence structure

Tags: grammar, adjectives, structure

I had this thing which bugged me for a while ,so I wanted to get it answered.
If I say ,for example, "The boy is nice." Is the word "nice" here an adjective? or just a noun in the sentence?

Comment: Of course it's an adjective.

Comment: You might want to google the word noun and the word adjective.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you think it might not be an adjective. Is it because you think that "adjectives are words that go in front of a noun to describe it".

Answer (score 1):

"Nice" is an adjective.

There's a common sentence pattern in English, "(noun) is (adjective)". This says that the adjective describes the noun. "The building is tall", "This class is hard", "My sister is annoying", etc.

There is a similar structure, "(noun) is (other noun)". The structure looks the same but the meaning is different. In this form, you are saying that the first noun and the second nouns describe the same person or thing. "The building is our headquarters", "This class is Math 204", "My sister is the vice president", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Adjectives is a word class that is characterised by a number of features.  The key features of adjectives are that

1. The can be used attributively "nice boy" or predicatively "the boy is nice".
2. They can form comparative forms "nicer", "nicest"
3. They can be modified with adverbs of degree "very nice", "quite nice".

Typical adjectives have all these properties, outlying adjectives don't have all these properties. ("freezing" and "enormous" for example can't really be modified for degree) A few adjectives are not used attributively and a few are not use predicatively.  And you need to take care to distinguish adjectives from nouns used attributively, and from verbs in a participle form, both of which can seem to be like adjectives.

Nouns on the other hand typically can form phrases with determiners and articles, and often have singular and plural forms, and can be modified by adjectives.

Nevertheless, "nice" clearly has all three properties of adjectives.  But it doesn't form phrases with an article "the nice", nor is there a plural form "nices"

And so Nice is undoubtedly a typical adjective.